# C# list join declaration

Tags: c#, list

I am not good with C# lists, because it is very confusing to me. So now I joined two tables into each other which looks like this:

```
var final = queryTable
    .Join(skillTable,
        query => query.Id_Skill,
        skill => skill.Id,
        (query, skill) => new { Id = query.Id, Name = query.Name, Line1 = skill.Line1, Line2 = skill.Line2, Line3 = skill.Line3, Line4 = skill.Line4, Line5 = skill.Line5 })
    .ToList();
```

So as you can see the new list hast the elements `Id`, `Name`, `Line1`, `Line2`, `Line3`, `Line4` and `Line5`.

What is the type of this list? 
What I mean is, how would I declare the list instead of var? I need this for further purpose.

Like:

```
List<theType> final = new List<theType>();
final = ...
```

Comment: you could try to create a class that has all those properties

Comment: Please don't offer voting advice in posts, it just creates work for volunteer editors - thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you need to reference this later you could create a class with all those properties like this

```
public class SomeName
{
  int id { get; set; }
  string Name { get; set; }
  string Line1 { get; set; }
  string Line2 { get; set; }
  string Line3 { get; set; }
  string Line4 { get; set; }
}
```

and change your query to create a new instance of this class

```
var final = queryTable
.Join(skillTable,
    query => query.Id_Skill,
    skill => skill.Id,
    (query, skill) => new SomeName() { Id = query.Id, Name = query.Name, Line1 = skill.Line1, Line2 = skill.Line2, Line3 = skill.Line3, Line4 = skill.Line4, Line5 = skill.Line5 })
.ToList();
```

Comment: `new SomeName()`? A list of empty objects won't be very useful.

Comment: @crashmstr yeah forgot to add it in but Samich fixed it

Comment: you can assign values to properties or create parametrized constructor

Comment: Thanks a lot!! That did it!

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation on [anonymous types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types): *(emphasis added)*

> Typically, when you use an anonymous type to initialize a variable, you declare the variable as an implicitly typed local variable by using var. ***The type name cannot be specified in the variable declaration because only the compiler has access to the underlying name of the anonymous type***. For more information about var, see [Implicitly Typed Local Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/implicitly-typed-local-variables).

If you'd like to reuse the type after the query has been executed, the best option is probably creating a class for just that purpose.

An alternative solution is to use `Tuple`, which saves you creating another class but is a pain to use if you plan on referencing the type in too many locations. I'd probably use the `Tuple` only if you plan on further manipulating the data within the same method.

```
(query, skill) => Tuple.Create(query.Id, query.Name, skill.Line1, skill.Line2,
                               skill.Line3, skill.Line4, skill.Line5 });
```

You'll end up with a `List<Tuple<int, string, .... >`

Answer (score 0):

You're creating an **anonymous** type using the `new { }` syntax. This means you can only use `var`, unless you specifically create a class with the same fields.